# Need Button to play .mp3 sound multiple times in succession

Tags: android

1)This is my main activity

```
package com.art.drumdrum;

import java.util.Timer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Timer time;
MainActivity p;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kick);

    Button kick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kick);
    kick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mpButtonClick.start();
        }
    });

}

}
```

2) this is my xml manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.art.drumdrum"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.art.drumdrum.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

3)this is my main layout xml ( mainly look at button id "kick")

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button7"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/kick"
    style="@style/style"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:text="kick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

4)Just want each button to have a sound and then be able to keep hitting them and the sounds overlap, right now it waits for the sound to end before it plays the next, even if im just hitting the same key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you only have one MediaPlayer object. If that is true, then it is one reason why you can only play one sample at time. Try using multiple MediaPlayer objects Perhaps one for each button?

I am still not certain if that will work though, it might be a limitation of the MediaPlayer class itself. In this case you'll want to use [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) instead, and make sure to set the max streams to something > 1.

It would look something like this:

```
sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
int streamID = sp.load(this, R.raw.sound, 1);
//....
sp.play(streamID, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

the `5` is this example is the max streams value, so if you need more than 5 streams at once change it.

Comment: thanks that makes since, sp has and error "sp cannot be resolved as variable?

Comment: put `SoundPool sp;` up near your other object declarations you can put it right underneath `Timer time;` and it should be good. Also I would recommend brushing up a bit on your java before you delve too far into Android, it will make your life so much easier =)

Comment: The method play(int, float, float, int, int, float) in the type SoundPool is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: whoops that one is my bad. I edited my answer to correct that. You'll need to add the other parameters for play Look on the javadoc page that I linked to find out what all of them do.